# Where does the windows file sharing account info save to?

Tags: windows-server-2003, file-sharing

OS: windows server 2003

When open explore and enter \\192.168.1.xxx\c$ and prompt to ask login id and password, where does this login info save to? And even if I choose not to save, seems the session will still remain until reboot? Can the community please suggestion some keyword to this and explain how it works a bit? Thanks.

Comment: r u talking about info thats saved to the security logs, or are you asking where does the username\password get stored?

Comment: username\password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question... I'd say it saves it internally to the workstation service and not to disk at all. It won't save password at all - it'll be a hash if it saves anything, and probably not the username either - I think it'll store an authenticated token that it can use to re-connect with.

Theory aside, in practical terms if you want to clean the connection, open a command prompt and type "`net use \\192.168.1.xxx /d`" which will delete the connection info and allow you to re-connect with different credentials.